# What books are the following ahadith collected in?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I would like to locate the source of some ahadith:

- The Prophet (S) used to say: “On the Day of Resurrection, I will identify my ummah by the mark of prostration that they have on their foreheads.”
- That portion of the earth on which prostration was made will testify to the devotion of man on the Day of Resurrection.
- And even in the world, a radiant point connect it to the heavens.

(These are three narrations of one hadith, I think)

Answer (score 0):

If you saw that hadith where I saw them, you can click on numbers to see where they are from. I will write it down just in case:

“On the Day of Resurrection, I will identify my ummah by the mark of prostration that they have on their foreheads.” (Musnad Ahmad ibn Hanbal, vol. 4, p. 189.)

That portion of the earth on which prostration was made will testify to the devotion of man on the Day of Resurrection.(Jami‘ al-Ahadith, vol. 5, p. 189.)

and even in the world, a radiant point connect it to the heavens. (Mustadrak al-Wasa’il, vol. 4, p. 485.)

**Edit**: and [here](http://www.al-islam.org/a-commentary-on-prayer-muhsin-qaraati/10.htm) is where I got this from.

Comment: Can you verify that the first part indeed appears in Musnad Ahmad? The last reference is a Shi'a reference book and I have no idea what "Jami` al-Ahadith" is or who wrote it. If it is indeed the case that this is a hadith that is only found in Shi'a books then that should be made clear in the answer (your source website is also a Shi'a website).

Comment: Since I don't have means to confirm, I made my answer community wiki. Everyone is welcome to edit&improve.

Comment: I found the same ahadith on [here](https://english.almaaref.org/essaydetails.php?eid=4667&cid=275) a shi'a website.